# Auto Class Completion of all the classes of a unit

Tags: class, delphi, autocomplete

I've created a function to extract Objects from a special JSON file extracted from SwaggerHub and create a unit for them. My functions is like this:

```
CreateUnit('d:\a.json', 'd:\MyAPI.pas');
```

And creates a unit like this:

```
unit MyAPI;

interface

type
  TType1 = class;
  TType2 = class;
  TType3 = class;
  ...

  TType1 = class
    property p1: TType1;
    property p2: TType2;
    property p3: String;
    property p4: Integer;
  end;

  TType2 = class
    property p1: TType1;
    property p2: TType3;
    property p3: String;
    property p4: Integer;
    property p5: Integer;
    property p6: string;
  end;

  ...

implementation

end.
```

This unit contains 133 classes and I want to apply the "Complete Class at Cursor" (Shift+Ctrl+C) on all classes. If I do it one by one, it takes a lot of time because every time I press Shift+Ctrl+C the cursor jumps to the bottom of the unit and I must go up and find the next uncompleted class.

Is there any Idea?

Comment: Shift-Ctrl-Up can help me to go up faster and seek the next class. But I'm looking for a better way.

Comment: Another way is to look for "end;" with Ctrl-F then repeat these: (Press Shift-Ctrl-C, then Shift-Ctrl-UP, then 2 times F3). Unfortunately this way is also time consuming and cannot be recorded as a Macro.

Comment: Why don't you just add writing the implementation part of the classes to your function, too? Besides that, the examples you provided don't need class completion because there are no methods. And they won't work anyway because a property needs at least a ``write`` or ``read`` statement.

Comment: Exactly @DelphiCoder. If you've taken the trouble to generate the interface section in your program, it will be easy to create stubs too.

Comment: That's right, I must do it. But it would be great if Embarcadero would add this feature as well.

Comment: Why would it be useful? If you are writing the interface yourself then you wouldn't need this. It would only be useful in your scenario, but in which case it's better to generate the implementation in your code.